# UI Elements display side by side. Not top to bottom

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56109/make-first-android-app-part-2) tutorial to learn Android development. I'm facing an issue regarding how to display controls on the screen.

If you check out the screenshots in that tutorial, all the UI elements are on the screen one after the other in a stacked manner. But when I do it it looks like this.

*Portrait*
[image]

As you can see only a couple of elements show up in the visible screen space. The rest is on to the right side off the screen. If I turn the screen to landscape orientation they are there.

[image]

Here is my `activity_main.xml` file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_textview"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything is written as the tutorial described.

In the tutorial however, they are using an emulator to run it. I'm using a [Micromax A74 Canvas](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a74_canvas_fun-5759.php) for testing purposes. But I ran the app in the same emulator but still I faced this exact problem.

Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks.

Comment: set `android:orientation="vertical"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: your parent `LinearLayout` does not have an `orientation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout needs declaration on appropriate orientation

`android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 2):

you should define orientation to LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout should look like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >  <!--here vertical-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_textview"
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   <!--here vertical-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
`android:orientation="vertical"`

to Set your layout view vertically...

Refer [This](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/) link to know basic difference about orientation changes..

Comment: Or Use [Android Layouts: Linear Layout, Relative Layout and Table Layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/) example to learn...